# installing msi file using powershell bringing up command line options

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the below command and it opens windows installers parameters, what am I doing wrong?

```
$current_pc     = "$env:computername"
$filePath      = "c:\users\ArA\Desktop\parameters.csv"
$machineParams = Import-CSV $filePath
$info          = if($machineParams){$machineParams | where {$_.branch -eq $($current_pc.Substring($current_pc.length - 3,3))}}
                 else{write-output "CSV not loaded"}
$info

start-process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList /L* "c:\users\Ara\Desktop\t.log" /qn /I "c:\users\Ar\Desktop\setup.msi" DATABASE_ID=$($info.DATABASE_ID),ODBC_DATABASE_NAME=$($info.ODBC_DATABASE_NAME),ODBC_ENGINE_NAME=$($info.ODBC_ENGINE_NAME) ODBC_HOST_NAME=$($info.ODBC_HOST_NAME) NOLAN=1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely how you are passing your arguments.  As a best-practice, I utilize an array when passing `exe` arguments so they're interpreted properly:

```
$machineParams = Import-Csv -Path $Env:UserProfile\Desktop\parameters.csv
$info = if ($machineParams) {
    $machineParams |
        Where-Object { $_.branch -eq $Env:ComputerName.Substring($Env:ComputerName.Length - 3, 3) }
} else {
    'CSV not loaded.'
}

$info

$StartArgs = @{
    'Wait'         = $true
    'FilePath'     = "$Env:SystemRoot\System32\msiexec.exe"
    'ArgumentList' = @(
        '/i',"$Env:UserProfile\Desktop\setup.msi"
        '/qn'
        '/log',"$Env:UserProfile\Desktop\t.log"
    )
}
if ($info -ne 'CSV not loaded.') {
    $StartArgs['ArgumentList'] += @(
        "DATABASE_ID=$($info.DATABASE_ID)"
        "ODBC_DATABASE_NAME=$($info.ODBC_DATABASE_NAME)"
        "ODBC_ENGINE_NAME=$($info.ODBC_ENGINE_NAME)"
        "ODBC_HOST_NAME=$($info.ODBC_HOST_NAME)"
        'NOLAN=1'
    )
}
Start-Process @StartArgs
```

Comment: Thanks,But the process is part of script, I have other msi running too

Comment: @dj3094 Did you even try what I posted?

Comment: i have couple other parameters too, how can i do that using your script

Comment: @dj3094 You would add them to the `ArgumentList` array.

Comment: $StartArgs = @{
    'FilePath'     = 'msiexec'
    'ArgumentList' = @(
        '/i','c:\setup.msi'
        '/qn'
        '/log','c:\setup.log'
    )
}
Start-Process @StartArgs

Comment: I ran this and its launching windows installer line options

Comment: @dj3094 In your question, you're passing your arguments incorrectly to `Start-Process` still. I've updated my answer according to your update.

Comment: the params looks good, but when it starts the msiexce it opens windows command line options